# Show Budget column to Position Column in sql

Tags: sql

My Table Structure

```
Designation_id  Budget
    102         6
    105         5
    106         2
```

Need Output.

```
Designation_ID   Position
    102          1
    102          2
    102          3
    102          4
    102          5
    102          6
    105          1
    105          2
    105          3
    105          4
    105          5
    106          1
    106          2
```

Is this is possible.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Look into `generate_series()` if you are using Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You need a table of numbers.  This can be created on the fly.  Here is typical syntax:

```
select s.designation_id, n.n as position
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6
     ) n join
     structure s
     on s.budget >= n.n;
```

The exact syntax for the subquery may vary, depending on the database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . No, I don't think so.  But, it might be clearer as `n.n <= s.budget`.